# using json_encode and echo in one php page

Tags: php

I'm using the below code to return values to the javascript file, I want just to return the json_encode value, while the echo value I want tp printed on the page without return it to javascript .. how could I do that?

Like the below code will return 1 or 2 and it will return the value that is inside the while loop while I just want to return the values that are inside the json_encode ..

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include "connect.php";
    $access = isset($_SESSION["userid"]);
    if ($access) {
        
        $nameID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "nameID", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

        if($nameID !== null && $nameID !== false){
            $SQL = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart where nameID = ?");
            if ($SQL->execute([$nameID])){
                if ($SQL->rowCount() > 0){
                    echo json_encode(1);
                }else{
                    $SQLI = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO cart VALUES (?,?,?)");
                    if ($SQLI->execute([$_SESSION["userid"], $nameID, 1])) {
                        if ($SQLI->rowCount() > 0) {
                            echo json_encode(2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        
        show the name list ..
        $SQLS = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from users where userid = ?"); 
        
        if ($SQLS->execute([$_SESSION["userid"]])){
            if ($SQLS->rowCount() > 0){
                while ($row = $SQLS->fetch()) {
                    echo "<br>" . $row ['userName'] . "<br>";           
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected JSON structure that you want the code the print out?

Comment: json_encode only encodes the value passed as parameter. This means that you are not passing nothing to javascript. The browser receives the response text as a unity. Said that, is store 1 and 2 in a javascript variable that do you want?